# VBA, Vlookup formula object required

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting object required run-time error '424'.

```
Dim LastRowTwo As Long, TargetRange As Variant, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Reconciliation")


    TargetRange = ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRowTwo)
        With TargetRange
            .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, 'ATP Final'!$G:$G, 1, FALSE), ""N/A"")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Targetrange` is currently declared as a variant and is missing the `Set` keyword on assignment. This is causing the line `TargetRange = ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRowTwo)` to implicitly add a `.value` and load the range's values into a two dimensional array. You want the actual range object with all its methods and properties.

```
Dim TargetRange As Range
...
set TargetRange = ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRowTwo)
...
```

Comment: @XLmatters This is presumably a snippet and that wasn't copied over, otherwise they never would have made it to the `.formula` line to get the error in the question.